# PF not defined in window.onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

If I execute following javascript with Primefaces (6.2.3) - but sometimes I get an error in firefox (not in other browsers):

> TypeError: PF(...) is undefined

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    init();
});

function init() {
    PF('selectOneMenuWidgetVar').selectValue("myvalue");
}
```

PF is defined in core.js of primefaces. Why PF could be undefined in some cases in firefox (52.8.0)? Is there a good way to ensure it is loaded before? I thought all resources should be loaded before?

Comment: If it works sometimes but not others then it could be a race condition as to which script loads first. How are you including them in the page?

Comment: Add [`defer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute to your `<script>` elements so that the browser would load js in a proper order.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: core.js is included in header-section:
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tirol.gv.at/primefaces/6.2.3/core.js"><!-- //--></script>

Comment: It is better to include js after the body so that the page doesn't have to wait for the whole js to load.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski: I try it at the end of the page. Lasts a while, because it's only happening sporadic.

Comment: Did you try to add [`defer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski: not possible in JSF - it expects a "=" after defer...

Comment: You can add `defer=defer`

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski: no change... I moved onLoad event at the end of the page - now it looks better, but it is difficult to say if it's fixed because it happens only occasionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the call of the init method to the end of the page was successful!

Comment: Thanks for posting your final solution.